# Concat two *ngfor variables in interpolation angular 4

Tags: angular, interpolation

```
     - *ngFor="let profile of allSupprotProfiles

     - *ngFor="let columnName of defaultColumns 


    <tr> <th>{{columnName}}</th> <td>{{ profile.{{columnName}}

 }}</td> </tr>
```

How can we concatenate with profile object?

Comment: please add more code and elaborate your post. Object structure?? UI expectation??

Comment: Two *ngfor loops are there one inside another and i wanted to use second loop variable as {{ profile.{{columnName}} }}.   First array is like :  [
    {
      "supportId": 2,
      "packageName": "Silver",
      "createdOn": "2018-03-27T11:23:48.000Z"
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this

```
<div *ngFor="let profile of allSupprotProfiles">
  <div *ngFor="let columnName of defaultColumns >
      <tr> <th>{{columnName}}</th> <td>{{ profile[columnName] }}</td> </tr>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read field value from the object, which you seems to be trying to do, you should use regular Javascript syntax:

```
{{ profile[columnName] }}
```